# How do the Thai air-traveling authorities determine if someone must be assigned a special seat reserved for at-risk passengers in the plane?

Tags: air-travel, thailand, covid-19

I read this quote from a flyer by the [PR Thai Government Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/thailandprd/) summarizing CAAT and airport authorities' new rules and measures:

> 7. Special seats must be reserved for at-risk passengers on routes longer than 90 minutes, to minimize contact between passengers.

[image]

([source](https://www.facebook.com/thailandprd/photos/a.251619424861479/3146161288740597/?type=3&theater))

How do the Thai air-traveling authorities determine if someone must be assigned a special seat reserved for at-risk passengers in the plane? In other words, when is a passenger regarded as high-risk?

Comment: Is there any reason to assume it is not the same as all over the world for many other reasons, like age and other health problems (which are well described.)

Comment: @Willeke no idea but I am not aware of any standard list.

Comment: Can you check whether there is a list published locally?

Comment: @Willeke I haven't found anything that. That's challenging to search because I don't speak Thai, and official information is often written in Thai.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.